# Generate Dump file using task manager

Tags: windows

I know that with Vista you can generate a dump file by goigg to task manager->processes-> right clicking on the process.

Is this option available in other versions of windows meaning Windows 7, Windows 2003, Windows 2008 etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is available in Windows 7 and 2008, but I don't know about Windows 2003. One thing to keep in mind is that on a 64 bit version of Windows, there are actually two versions of Task Manager - one 32 bit and one 64 bit. If you use the 64 bit, you'll get a 64 bit dump, even if the process is 32 bit. I.e. you'll get all the Wow64 in the process as well. However, if you use the 32 bit version of Task Manager, you'll get a 32 bit dump without the Wow64 stuff. The latter is significantly easier to debug as the abstraction layer isn't present in the dump.

Comment: You said there are 2 versions of Task Manager. How can I launch/open both of them?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to have both of them run at the same time.

Comment: Okay. How can I run them one-by-one ?

Answer (score 0):

To collect a 32 bit dump, by opening a 32 bit task manager found at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe

Check in process explorer that it has a (32) to it