# Is there a way a customer can force a crash (which then will generate a minidump) during a "long" Windows API call?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Our app is "hanging" at a customer site (not really, it's just a really long call to some Windows Networking API call, where there is a disabled VPN adapter, and it needs to time out - minutes?).  We cannot duplicate it (we don't have his VPN setup), but customer can easily duplicate it.

Our app generates mini dump (*.dmp) files when it crashes.  **Is there a way to get an end-customer to generate an immediate crash (specifically during this long API call), so we can see where it is hanging?**

I have tried "Ending the Process" via Task Manager, but that must "gracefully" shut down the app, because a .dmp file is NOT generated using Task Manager.

This is a release build of an MFC C++ app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to crash to generate a dump file. Simply open up Task Manager, go to *Processes* tab, rightclick the respective process and choose *Create dump file*:
[image: Task Manager - Processes tab]

Once the dump is written to disk Task Manager will pop up a dialog informing the user, where the dump file is located. By default it is *%temp%\<image name>.DMP*:
[image: Dumping process]

For 32 bit applications, to create a 32 bit dump file, run the 32 bit version of Task Manager from Window's SysWOW64 folder : e.g. c:\Windows\SysWOW64\Taskmgr.exe

Comment: I tried it 3 dialog levels deep in my app.  I got the dump file, but all of the threads stack frames are extremely shallow (8 deep), and they all look the same, including the Main Thread:> wow64cpu.dll!0000000074842e09()  
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for wow64cpu.dll] 
  wow64cpu.dll!0000000074842bf1()  
  wow64.dll!00000000748bd286()  
  wow64.dll!00000000748bc69e()  
  ntdll.dll!00000000774cd447()  
  ntdll.dll!000000007747c34e()

Comment: It's a 32-bit MFC app running on Win7 64 bit

Comment: Since you haven't loaded symbols (*"no symbols loaded for wow64cpu.dll"*) the stack frames are incorrect or missing. See [Specify Symbol (.pdb) and Source Files in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx) for detailed instructions on how to set up your debugging environment.

Comment: I have VS2008.  I copied all my .PDB to the same folder as the original .EXE, and copied the .DMP from my temp folder here.  When I run the debugger on the .DMP file, it says it still cannot find symbols.  I tried to follow the VS2008 Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and added that folder to eh "locations" list, and it did not work.  I then tried to load the symbols after "running" the .DMP by specifying that same folder as the "Cache symbols" list and hit the "Load symbols using above locations" button, and it still could not resolve the symbols.

Comment: *wow64cpu.dll* is a module that ships with Windows. You need to use Microsoft's public symbol server. [How to: Use a Symbol Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) outlines the setup for Visual Studio 2008. If a public symbol server is impractical for you, you can also download symbol files for Windows: [Download Windows Symbol Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx).

Comment: @franji1 Your question as to how to create a dump file has been answered. You should post a new question if you need help with how to use it, rather than ask for help here in the comments.

Comment: I also noticed that it is probably not a "mini" dump (based on the size), which is always more beneficial when trying to debug.  Still need to get those symbols loaded.  I won't bother posting a question on that until I have tried to figure it out, especially with the bread crumbs posted by @IInspectable and any other posts on SO or elsewhere.

Comment: Found this SO Q/A with some critical information regarding the issues I am having with my dump file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070646/generate-dump-file-using-task-manager .  I need to run the 32 bit version of Task Manager on my 32-bit app running on Win7 64 bit in order to generate the correct dump file.

Comment: @franji1: This is interesting information, but does not at all address the issues you were having. Your issues were caused by failing to load symbol information for system modules. You will have identical issues with a 32-bit dump file (even though the call stacks may appear to be a bit more complete). You'll still get the *"Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing"* warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinDbg to create the minidump:
http://wiki.zimbra.com/index.php?title=Creating_a_Core_Dump_from_a_Running_Process_using_WinDbg

This will tell you where it is, when you break. Obviously, it won't use your handler to create the dump, but if you're just worried about the hang location, this should be sufficient. Visual studio has similar functionality to create a dump from a running process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your crash reporter, this will provoke a nice access violation:

```
int *p = 0x0;
*p = 0xbadf00d;
```